# How to create an if/then boolean string to execute autoclick

Tags: java, click, awt

I'm trying to create a simple Java GUI window in which when I a number is placed in the window, the program determines what the value of the number is (ie greater than 2, or less than 2), and then executes an autoclick depending on the int value.

```
private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   for (int field = 0; field <= 2; field++) {
      if (field <= 2) {
         (EXECUTE AUTOCLICK;
      }
      else if ( field >= .15 ) {
            do nothing
```

Obviously it's broken and the 'EXECUTE AUTOCLICK' is not a function, but I figured i'd put it in to show what i'm trying to accomplish.

Additionally, how would I add an auto click function into the code and where would I add it?

Can you tell tell that I'm a noob?

Comment: You mean simulating a click event ? Use a robot.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: you need the keyPress https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress(int)

Comment: Please provide the whole code.

Comment: What are you trying to click? a Button? Robot seems overkill unless you are literally trying to simulate a mouse click, and even then it's undesirable as it uses the system API.  Better to simulate it, but I'd need more information to provide an answer

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to simulate a mouse click. There is a website with a button that starts a certain process for our company, and this program is designed to press that button only when a certain condition has been met.

Comment: Why don't you start the certain process instead of clicking with the mouse on a button? You also would have to adjust your mouse position for the click - so that you don't miss the button while you click. Btw, your else-if-case will never run as it is either not reached or not true.